# HTML input not working correctly with AJAX update panels used else where on page

Tags: .net, html, vb.net, ajax, input

I have some update panels on my page that do some asyncpostbacks to keep some dropdownlists correctly populated. My problem is that on my page i have an HTML input that is handling some file uploads. With the AJAX on the page with asyncpostbacks, and while i step through my code behind, the files arent being uploaded. Using a postbacktrigger (non-async) is not possible because of my layout.

Here is my code:

```
      <div id="divFileInputs" runat="server">
                     <input id="file1" name="fileInput" type="file" runat="server" size="50" style="width: 50em"
                         onfocus="AddFileInput()" class="textbox" /></div>
                 <select id="selectFileList" name="ListBox1" size="5" style="width: 50em; text-align: left;"
                     class="textbox" />
                 <input id="RemoveAttachmentButton" type="button" value="Remove" onclick="RemoveFileInput()"
                     class="removebutton " />
             </div>
```

Here is my code behind:

```
Protected Sub CopyAttachments(ByVal issueId As String)

    Dim files As HttpFileCollection = Request.Files
    Dim myStream As System.IO.Stream

    Dim service As New SubmitService.Service
    For i As Integer = 0 To files.Count - 1

        Dim postedFile As HttpPostedFile = files(i)
        Dim fileNameWithoutPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName)

        If fileNameWithoutPath.Length > 0 And issueId.Length > 0 Then
            Dim fileLength As Integer = postedFile.ContentLength
            Dim fileContents(fileLength) As Byte

            ' Read the file into the byte array.  Send it to the web service.
            myStream = postedFile.InputStream
            myStream.Read(fileContents, 0, fileLength)
            service.ClearQuestAttachToIssue(issueId, fileNameWithoutPath, fileContents)
        End If
    Next

    service = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I put a breakpoint in at the declaration of service and then check the value of "files", the count is 0. I am expecting it to be 2 when i have one file uploaded.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the solution. The submit button that I used was attached to an AJAX asncypostback. Thus not posting back the whole page. I changed it to just a postback update panel and bingo..works!